# AJAX call, add loader only when loading posts

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax call where on click on the section I'll load posts (the featured images assigned to them) from the category that are assigned to that section. It all works well, except from a few things.

1: I have a loader that will appear when my images (from the posts) are being loaded to a second div. Then when the loading of the posts in the div is complete, that div gets a class that triggers it's transition, so that it's visible, loader gets a `loaded` class, and no ajax loader is present. But, when I click to hide the second div (gallery), the loader appears again, and then the transition happens. How to make it that on second click I won't have the loader and just have the transition that hides that div immediately?

I'm doing this from wordpress. My ajax looks like this.

```
var $content = $("#gallery");
var $content_inner = $("#inner_gallery");
var $fullPage = $('#fullpage');
var $galleryCat = $('#fullpage').find('.section');
var $close = $('.close');
var $loader = $("#loader");  
var catID;
var order;
var orderby;

$('#fullpage').find('.section').eq(0).addClass('first');

$galleryCat.each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        catID = $(this).data('cat');
        order = $(this).data('order');
        orderby = $(this).data('orderby');
        load_posts(catID, order, orderby);
        if(!$(this).hasClass('first')){
            $fullPage.toggleClass('galleryShow');
        }
        if (!$content.hasClass('galleryShow')) {
            $content_inner.scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
});

function load_posts(currentCat, order, orderby){
    var str = '&cat=' + currentCat + '&order=' + order + '&orderby=' + orderby + '&action=gallery_posts';
    $content_inner.html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType   : "html",
        url: get_gallery_posts.ajaxurl,
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
            var $data = $(data);
            if ($data.length) {
                $content_inner.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $content_inner.html(data);
                    $content.toggleClass('galleryShow');
                });
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function(){
            $loader.removeClass('loaded').addClass('loading');
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        },
        complete : function(){
            $loader.removeClass('loading').addClass('loaded');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section" data-cat="category1" data-catName="Category1" data-order="ASC" data-orderby="title" style="background:url(\''.$image_url.'\'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;"></div>
<div class="section" data-cat="category2" data-catName="Category2" data-order="ASC" data-orderby="title" style="background:url(\''.$image_url.'\'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;"></div>
<div class="section" data-cat="category3" data-catName="Category3" data-order="ASC" data-orderby="title" style="background:url(\''.$image_url.'\'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;"></div>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="inner_gallery"></div>
</div>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

So when you click on a section, you get all the info from it, then pass that into a function that will query all the posts, and then those posts will appear in the `#inner_gallery`.

All of this works, but needs some tweaking. Making the loader not loading when hiding the gallery, and resetting the scroll position of the inner gallery.

EDIT: I've sorted the scroll issue:

```
if (!$content.hasClass('galleryShow')) {
    $content_inner.scrollTop(0);
}
```

Still the loader issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it all

```
var $content = $("#gallery");
var $content_inner = $("#inner_gallery");
var $fullPage = $('#fullpage');
var $galleryCat = $('#fullpage').find('.section');
var $close = $('.close');
var $loader = $("#loader");  
var catID;
var order;
var orderby;

$('#fullpage').find('.section').eq(0).addClass('first');

$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('#fp-nav').append('<div class="closed_nav"></div>');
});

$galleryCat.each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        catID = $(this).data('cat');
        order = $(this).data('order');
        orderby = $(this).data('orderby');
        if(!$(this).hasClass('first')){
            $fullPage.toggleClass('galleryShow');
        }
        if (!$content.hasClass('galleryShow')) {
            load_posts(catID, order, orderby);
            $content_inner.scrollTop(0);
        }

        if ($content.hasClass('galleryShow')) {
            $content.removeClass('galleryShow')
        }

    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#fp-nav', function(){
    $content.removeClass('galleryShow');
    $fullPage.removeClass('galleryShow');
});

function load_posts(currentCat, order, orderby){
    var str = '&cat=' + currentCat + '&order=' + order + '&orderby=' + orderby + '&action=gallery_posts';
    $content_inner.html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType   : "html",
        url: get_gallery_posts.ajaxurl,
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
            var $data = $(data);
            if ($data.length) {
                $content_inner.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $content_inner.html(data);
                    $content.toggleClass('galleryShow');
                });
            }
        },
        beforeSend : function(){
            $loader.removeClass('loaded').addClass('loading');
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        },
        complete : function(){
            $loader.removeClass('loading').addClass('loaded');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Just remove classes. Also I added additional on click event that will remove classes when you click the navigation between sections, that is added by fullPage.js

:)